# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch defining PivotCahe

Tags: vba, excel, methods, type-mismatch

I get the error `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` when defining the `PivotCache` and creating the Pivot Table for my Ribbon Macro. Can anyone please explain why and how to fix it?

```
Dim PCache As PivotCache
'Define Pivot Cache and Insert Pivot Table
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Assigned!$A:$P"). _
    CreatePivotTable(Worksheets("Assigned").Range("R3"), TableName:="Assigned` Cases")
```

Comment: I have also tried  `TableDestination:="Assigned!$R$3"` and it doesn't work :/

Comment: In case you don't already know, you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50650662/edit) to include more information (such as the `TableDestination` line).

Comment: It looks like you have `Set PCache = ...Create().CreatePivotTable()`.  Try breaking that into multiple lines (`Set x=...Create()`, then `Set PCache=x.CreatePivotTable`).  Sometimes VBA can't decipher nested statements properly.

Comment: Wonderful! That did the trick @cxw!!  Thanks !!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single statement (`Set PCache = ...Create().CreatePivotTable()`) that includes a chain of method calls.  Sometimes VBA can't decipher nested statements properly, so try breaking that into multiple lines:

```
Dim x as ...
Set x = ...Create(...)
Set PCache = x.CreatePivotTable(...)
```